# change jQuery from random to one by one slideshow

Tags: jquery, random

I'm trying to get rid of the random function in a slideshow I'm using. the iRnd variable passes the value to loader; I've tried to use `for (i=0; i<= aImages.lenght, i++) {iRnd=i}` but that does not get the job done. I just want to get rid of the random, and get images one by one in the order they're in the array.

Here's my code:

```
function LoadImages()
{

    /* Select a random image number and make sure this is not equal to the previous image */
    while(iPrev == iRnd)
    {
        iRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*aImages.length);
    }

    /* Show the selected image */
    LoadImage(iRnd);

    iPrev = iRnd;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [modulus operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29) to help you wrap around when you reach the end. This should work for you:

```
function LoadImages(){

    iRnd = (iRnd + 1) % aImages.length;

    /* Show the selected image */
    LoadImage(iRnd);

};
```

However you should avoid having so many global variables in your code (I'm assuming `aImages` and `iRnd` are both global).